# Laravel 5 not find http://localhost:8000/css/app.css

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 5 and got "Failed to load resource, the server responded with a status of 404(Not Found) http://localhost:8000/css/app.css"

If my layout.blade.php were

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

It works fine.

But If I changed it to

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/app.css') }}">
```

I got

http://localhost:8000/css/app.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I have public/css/app.css
which I got from gulp and it clearly exists these.

If I entered http://localhost:8000/css/app.css from browser URL, I got an error NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:" because I do not write /css/app.css at routes.php.

But I do not think this is a routing issue.

I know very similiar issue in Stack Overflow but can not find specific solutions.

Comment: @Mr.Engineer He had mentioned in the question that css has been placed in public folder. Read question properly before making a comment.
1. Check permission for your public/css folder.
2. try to use `url('public/css/app.css')` or `asset('css/app.css)`

Comment: Ops. Sorry for mistake.

Comment: try `href="{{ URL::asset('public/css/app.css') }}">` if it doesn't work it is a file permision error

Comment: Sounds great but still got another error.

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8000/public/css/app.css".

Comment: I am trying Windows 7 Xampp, so the file permission is not a problem.

Comment: I was able to access my file in the public folder by going to localhost:8000/css/app.css . This does not need to be included in the routes. Check properly being generated correctly by gulp. Or just try to put a dummy css file in the /css directory and check if that works.

Comment: Also try @madalinivascu solution but with the attribute type="text/css"  in your link tag.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
There was no problem from the beginning.

The initial setting was correct.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/app.css') }}">
```

The problem seems to be caused by Netbeans 8.1 embedded web server.

I was trying to test Windows 7 + Netbeans 8.1 embedded web server and always testing my program with http://xxx:8000/.

The problem seems to be caused by Netbeans 8.1 embedded web server.

Now I am using Xampp embedded Apache and works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load using this syntax

```
{!! Html::style('css/all.css') !!}
```

in this case your all.css file located into public/css/all.css